# objdump and gdb spits different assembly results

Tags: gdb, executable, objdump

[image]

you'll need to save the image to read the instructions in the image

well, here's the problem.

I'm working on a bomblab just for killtime and I'm stuck with the issue

of different assembly code generation of objdump and gdb.

my laptop is running 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and

I've installed 32bit glibc to work on bomblab.(since it's compiled in 32-bit env)

well, first the symbols aren't showing and I don't really get what gdb is spitting out.

Can someone explain me what's going on?

Comment: Waht do you get in gdb if you disassemble `phase_2` before running the code?

Comment: @mofoe in fact, I can't get the disassembled result before running the code

Comment: oh. any idea why that is? what happens if you open gdb and enter > `disas phase_2` ?

Comment: remove the breakpoint at `phase_2` after it's hit, then `disass` the code and see whether it looks more like what you expect. The `int3` is the breakpoint instruction the debugger placed there, and a few following disassembled instructions are going to be wrong until the series of instructions gets "resynchronized".

Comment: Good point! id up vote this comment!

Comment: @MarkPlotnick ahh~ thnx now it works, but what was the problem? I mean why is it different?

Comment: It's different because `gdb` placed a breakpoint instruction near the top of `phase_2`. I've written an explanation below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you placed a breakpoint at `phase_2`, `gdb` patched the running image to place an `int3` instruction at 0x8048b50, which is just after `phase_2`'s function prologue has finished setting up the stack frame. So instead of

```
0x8048b50: 8b  mov edx,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
0x8048b51: 55
0x8048b52: 08
```

you now have

```
0x8048b50: cc  int3
0x8048b51: 55  push ebp
0x8048b52: 08  first byte of an 'or' instruction
```

and that is what `gdb` is displaying. Eventually things get synced back up and the `disassemble` command starts to display the correct series of instructions.

The difference in what is displayed won't affect correct execution of the program; before proceeding from the breakpoint, `gdb` will either place that 8b byte back into the image or it will synthetically execute the `mov` instruction and then continue execution at 0x8048b53.